# Upgrading to MySQL 5.7.15 crashes on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, mysql

Last night I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu OS and MySQL 5.7.15 was one of the changes. It seems upgrading is successfull because mysql is propely working, but installation proccess has stop working with this message:

```
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.15, 
use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
```

I can't cancel the installation proccess in reqular way and just have to kill it. So it may cause some problem and also for every other installation (in the future) it tries to do it again.

How to prevent this upgrade or solve it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This solution solved my problem:

1. Back-up your database files with permissions:

   ```
   sudo cp -avt /your/backup/directory /var/lib/mysql /etc/mysql/my.cnf
   ```
2. Delete mysql files:

   ```
   sudo rm -rv /etc/mysql
   ```
3. Remove MySQL completely via running:

   ```
   sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7
   ```

   *Use of [Synaptic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/) is recommended.*
4. Create these folders:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /etc/mysql/conf.d
   ```

   *mysql setup didn't do it automatically and I don't know why.*
5. Install MySQL again

   ```
   sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```

   *I used `sudo apt install lamp-server^` instead to install other dependencies for PHP development.*
6. Stop MySQL:

   ```
   sudo service mysql stop
   ```
7. Restore databases and files:

   ```
   sudo cp -a /your/backup/directory/mysql /var/lib   
   sudo cp /your/backup/directory/my.cnf /etc/mysql
   ```
8. Restart MySQL:

   ```
   sudo service mysql start
   ```

Comment: dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7

Comment: Key thing is removing: `sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/config.dat`, `sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat` and `sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat`. Then purge everything. Then do a system reboot.

Comment: I had same problem and solved it with this procedure. I recommend a system reboot after purging MySQL. It seems that this prevents the issue reported by Stevie.

Comment: Error come backs with the next MySQL update :(

Answer (score 10):

An easy solution is to `sudo killall mysqld` while the apt-get operation is running.

The apt operation just kept on running without any errors after that(!)

Comment: This actually worked. Have my upvote

Comment: Probably best answer.

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix this without having to purge everything. It seems the problem is that the sys schema database was never created, so here's the solution:

1. Clone https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys and cd into the cloned folder.
2. In a terminal, run mysql -u root -p < ./sys_57.sql (or sys_56.sql, depending on your version)

Enjoy mysql_upgrade working again. I guess this probably was, an upgrading scripts mess-up.

Comment: Yes it is an issue with upgrading databases. Unfortunately I can't test your solution anymore to see if it's working or not.

Comment: I tried this solution on my mysql 5.7.22 installation that was reporting "This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.22, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade" and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

If your root@`localhost` account has no password then there is a bug in the postinstall process as stated [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1817374)
(see particularly the last comment of the thread)

- purge all `TMP*` files in `/var/lib/mysql-files`
- edit the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst` and comment (using #) the line 370 :

  `echo "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH 'auth_socket';" >> "$initfile"`
- run again `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Oh dear me ! <3 You saved my life :p Note for posterity : you may want to prevent further mysql update (which will fail the same way) using `apt-mark hold mysql-server-5.7`

Comment: This saved my day! Running Ubuntu 18.x via Vagrant, and indeed: No password for root, so it was stuck.

Comment: Worked perfectly! thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too. Every time I started apt get and installed the process would hang after or during the DB update. None of the other solutions here worked.

In the end I purged

```
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
```

And followed the manual install from the instructions for mysql [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-installation.html)

I then overwrote the data directory with my old data

```
sudo cp -Rfv /var/lib/mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
```

and finally added a systemd service like this

/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service

```
[Unit]
Description=MySQL Server
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mysql:mysql -R /var/run/mysqld
ExecStart=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
TimeoutSec=300
PrivateTmp=true
User=mysql
Group=mysql
WorkingDirectory=/usr

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then ran

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl enable mysql
# systemctl start mysql
```

Then everything seemed to be working as before and mysql was not breaking system updates

The downside, of course, is that I'll need to do manual updates in the future.