# Ubuntu 16.04, apt-get upgrade leads to freezing without errors on MySQL server 5.7

Tags: upgrade, mysql, freeze

I'm trying to upgrade my system using

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The process freezes without any errors saying: 
"This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.17, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade"

I tried using https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys and loading sys_57.sql but it didn't help.

There're no options, it's just freezing. The only way is to stop the process. In this case it says: "subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted"
How can I proceed with upgrading?

Comment: kill the related dpkg process then https://askubuntu.com/a/1143196/622094

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing this exact same thing, there appears to be a bug where the upgrade starts a new MySQL process that does not exit.  What worked for me was to manually kill the mysql process that the install started.  Something like this:

1. Run your apt-get install command (or whatever lead to this).
2. Wait for it to get to the stuck state with: **This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.21, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade** (or similar).
3. Do a "ps axu" on another terminal.
4. You (should?) see a process something like **mysqld --user=mysql --init-file=/var/lib/mysql-files/tmp.14GvWpndwp --socket=/tmp/tmp.XwilP9D8VF/mysqld.sock --pid-file=/tmp/tmp.8V9FXDwilP/mysqld.pid**  Note all of the temporary directories it's using, this appears to be an upgrade command that is not exiting.
5. Kill that process

This should let the apt-get process proceed.  I noticed that the upgrade script is sending a "stop" command (process) that is not obeyed by the MySQL process, so it's probably patiently waiting for MySQL to stop.  That's the observation lead me to this path.

Comment: When the upgrade failed, I automatically stated searching for solutions, but this answer makes sense based on the error messages.

Comment: For anyone running mysql in a docker container, you can kill the mysqld processes in a terminal on the host. Attempting to attach to the container additional times will only display the upgrade screen each time.